# How to search for a IP address in git?

Tags: string, git, search, github, ip

Unable to search for a specific IP in git. When I try 10.x.x.x it gives me results matching one of the x and if I give "10:x:x:x" sometimes it gives me results some time it doesn't. Please let me know how to search in git UI under an organization?

Comment: you are using git grep? perhaps something like ```git grep -E "10\..*\..*\..*"``` might work.

Comment: And what is your scenario? What is exact command you are executing? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: import logging
import urllib2
import re
from contextlib import closing

def get_ip(url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org/"):
    '''Get local machine (or router)'s external IP from a IP checking web
    service.
    url: the URL of the IP checking service. Default to
    http://checkip.dyndns.org/
    '''
    with closing(urllib2.urlopen(url)) as f:
        b = f.read()
        # trim off htmls
        b = re.sub(r'.*\<body\>(.*)\</body\>.*', r'\1', b)
        ip = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', b)[0]
        logging.info("Current IP: {}".format(ip))
        return ip

Comment: I am trying to search this in git UI under an organization which has multiple repos under it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the search bar:

```
"10.x.x.x" in:file
```

Comment: I meant try using this format in the search bar....